# Question about ideals in rings

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

> Show that the ideal $\langle 5\rangle$ is a maximal ideal in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

I have a point in my mind regarding the above question. Should we consider ideal $\langle 5\rangle$ as ideal $\langle 5\mathbb{Z}\rangle$?

Thank you for now

Comment: By definition, is $R$ is a ring and $S$ is a subset of $R$, then $\langle S\rangle$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ that contains $S$. For singletons, we usually write $\langle a\rangle$ rather than $\langle\{a\}\rangle$. So $\langle 5\rangle$ is “the smallest ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ that contains $5$.” Similalry, $\langle 5\mathbb{Z}\rangle$ means “the smallest ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ that contains every element of the form $5m$, with $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.” You should convince yourself that the ideal designated in each case is the exact same ideal.

Comment: So what is the definition of $\langle x \rangle$, and what is meant by the notation $5 \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The notation $\langle 5\mathbb Z\rangle$ is redundant, by the way. $5\mathbb Z$ is sufficient.

Comment: @DonThousand Why not? The notation $\langle A \rangle$ works for *any* subset of the ring, and if $A$ is already an ideal, then $\langle A \rangle = A$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Except $5$ isn't a subset of $R$, it's an element. Though we can add a double meaning to those definitions by saying for an element $x$, $\langle x \rangle$ is short for $\langle\{x\}\rangle$.

Comment: @aschepler: Fair enough.

Comment: @azif00 It's redundant, for the exact reason you mention.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

First $\mathbf Z$ is a P.I.D.

Second, $a\mathbf Z\subset b\mathbf  Z$ means $b$ divides $a$. If $a=5$, what can you deduce for $b$?